# Document Sets & Content Types

Tags: 2010, content-type, document-set

Our users generally work offline - hence we want an ability in Document Set whereby

1. Documents can be uploaded in a Document Set
2. The Uploader is asked - Which Document Set should be used to uploaded to...
3. The document being uploaded can be jpeg or pdf files.

So we basically I want Document Set like association (grouping of docs in one item) for jpeg, pdf files which are to be uploaded and the decision - which content type the doc should be - is put on the uploader.

Is it possible?